# Infrared Sensor Activation Problems

Tags: ev3

I tried running my EV3 program that requires an infrared sensor, but it didn't work. I looked at the port view on the app and I saw the infrared sensor. It was connected, the brick recognized it but had a "---" on it. I tried restarting it, but nothing seemed to work. Any suggestions?

Comment: Try a different input port. Try a different cable. Try a different EV3. Try a different sensor.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions! I tired a diffrent cable and it worked!

Comment: Hmm, Nice because your cable is not short-circuited or malfunction anymore.

Answer (score 0):

That occurs sometimes if the cable is not fully plugged in. Try pushing the cable in where it connects to the sensor and the brick.